# Can't build and deploy ts expo native app to Amplify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, expo, aws-amplify

I'm getting error like this in each build I do:

```
`ERR! Cannot read property '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native' of undefined
2023-07-02T21:22:08.748Z [WARNING]: 
2023-07-02T21:22:08.749Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-02T21_22_08_735Z-debug.log
2023-07-02T21:22:08.749Z [HELP]: Outputting the npm debug log
                                 [object Promise]
2023-07-02T21:22:08.758Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-07-02T21:22:08.759Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-07-02T21:22:08.759Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-07-02T21:22:08.760Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...

`
```

Though I have the latest version of ui-react-native installed, the dependencies in package.lock are present and so on.

I tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules folder. Didn't work.

Maybe someone had faced this issue?